# Is power density invariant to Fourier Transform? Does it hold through derivation?

Tags: power-spectral-density, proof

### Assumptions

We have a finite discrete measurement.

### Introduction

I had some troubles determining a power spectral densities needed for Wiener deconvolution. Looking through the continuous equations of FT applied to power and spectral power it seemed like they should be basically equal. Then I got distributions involved, resulting in following proof.

Let $<P|\varphi>$ be a distribution (linear continuous functional on set of testing functions $\varphi$).  Define $P$ as $$P(\varphi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\varphi^{2}(x)dx}$$
Let us have a Fourier transform of a distribution (can prove this one), $$< F(P) |\varphi>=<P|F(\varphi)>$$
Then let us demonstrate the equality:$$<F(P)|F^{-1}(\varphi)>=<P|F(F^{-1}(\varphi))>=<P|\varphi>$$
Plugging in the definition of the distribution, we get:$$P(\varphi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\varphi^{2}(x)dx}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{F(\varphi)F^{-1}(\varphi)dx}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{F(\varphi)F^{*}(\varphi)dx}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{{|F(\varphi)|}^2dx}$$ Thus proving the invariance of total power included in the signal.
This holds on through simulations (ratio between total power and total spectral power converges to 1).

### SNR ratio

Wiener deconvolution uses a ratio of power densities of a signal and some noise. For a fixed range over which we assume the density, explicitly the range on which the signal is non-zero, we should be able to determine explicit ratio needed. Using all the assumptions, I was able to contradict this approach via derivatives.

Let us have a derivation of a distribution (also provable):$$<P'|\varphi>=-<P|\varphi>$$ Therefore the negation should cancel itself in the desired ratio, however it does not (using the same simulation, it simply varies).

### Question

Somewhere I had to make a mistake. I suppose it happens in continuous theory when I subconsciously multiply by Dirac's comb, or when I assume the same length in the density formula $$\int_{-a}^{a}{\frac{f(x)dx}{2a}}$$

### Plea

I hope I just need another pair of eyes, because if a theorem holds, a result is derived and observed, a theorem is used again and it contradicts itself, there **must** be something wrong...